# Cannot reload apache

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

I'm trying to set up a subdomain but upon enabling it and reloading apache, I get this error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl status apache2.service shows:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
   Active: active (running) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-09-01 01:03:23 UTC; 10h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5359 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─2732 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2733 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2734 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2735 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2736 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2841 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─4037 SCREEN -d -m -S hft-run
           ├─4040 /bin/sh
           ├─4041 tail -n0 -f -s 0.01 /home/duke/script.txt
           ├─4043 /bin/sh
           ├─4044 tee -a /home/duke/script2.txt
           ├─4054 SCREEN -d -m -S hft-script
           ├─4057 /bin/sh


Sep 01 11:30:12 rx-texas systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Apache2 web server.
Sep 01 11:30:12 rx-texas apache2[5320]: Reloading web server: apache2 failed!
Sep 01 11:30:12 rx-texas apache2[5320]: Apache2 is not running ... (warning).
Sep 01 11:30:12 rx-texas systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 01 11:30:12 rx-texas systemd[1]: Reload failed for LSB: Apache2 web server.
Sep 01 11:34:21 rx-texas systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Apache2 web server.
Sep 01 11:34:21 rx-texas apache2[5359]: Reloading web server: apache2 failed!
Sep 01 11:34:21 rx-texas apache2[5359]: Apache2 is not running ... (warning).
Sep 01 11:34:21 rx-texas systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 01 11:34:21 rx-texas systemd[1]: Reload failed for LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

Here are journalctl -xe logs: http://pastebin.com/wc7XFmpG

And  `apache2ctl configtest` shows `Syntax OK`

I'm running Apache/2.4.16 (Debian sid)

Comment: Anything relevant in your httpd error log ?